# does intel 82579lm gigabit network connection support wol?

Tags: windows-10, wake-on-lan

I have an on-Board intel 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection on my HPz420 PC which runs Win 10 Pro x64bit. In the Networkadapter settings there isn't the "Active Magic Packets" option, in order to be able to activate Wake on Lan. Even though I could activate WOL in BIOS, if the network adapter itself hadn't the option to activate wol, it would not work. Does anyone know, if this network adapter support wol or not ?

Comment: Yes it does, I would not trust anything in Windows to do the right thing, get the right tools for the job.

Comment: thx for your time.. I could not find the "Activate magic Package" option in the advanced Opetion of the networkadapter. Which means, wol won't work out. That's why I am asking this question. Do u have this option ?

Comment: Maybe you should instead explain what you are trying to do, and what is not working, also include what you have tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, 82579LM has WOL, I have not seen any NIC that does not have it since NE2000 nics.

When I think about WOL I think about power on from power off mode. (not really wake from sleep)

Not all features that a NIC has can be changed in all versions of the Windows driver, and some features can not be changed at all.

Sure, NICs have registers that can be modified to change features, but few (if any) store these, so the only time any options in a windows driver would have any effect is after windows boots, so potentially when a machine goes to sleep. but on system reset, and power off, they would be irrelevant.

Consider for a moment that you turn of the machine by pulling the plug, this resets the NIC entirely, now plug in the power, and use WOL to start the machine, note that no Windows driver would have had the chance to modify the registers on the NIC to modify WOL settings.

When you enable WOL in BIOS:

1. Super IO is configured in NVRAM to react to WOL signal from NIC
2. Enables SB power to NIC, other settings are irrelevant.

Now let's look on the drivers in [Wired_driver_26.4_x64.exe](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/47620/intel-82579lm-gigabit-ethernet-phy/downloads.html)`\PRO1000\Winx64\NDIS63\` there is `e1c63x64.inf` here we can find `82579LM` and in turn `Powermgmt.reg` - Note that these settings are in regards to "wake from sleep" (this is driver ver 03/29/2016,12.15.31.4) So if you want' these settings, make sure to install a driver that has them.

A quick search [found this](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/sv-se/000129137/wake-on-lan-wol-troubleshooting-best-practices?lang=en) that especially mentions the NIC in question.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @NiKiZe's answer: some drivers (especially those included in Windows) explicitly *deactivate WoL on shutdown*, even if there's no option to activate it.

To verify, remove power from the PC, replug after a few seconds. You should see the link come up when still powered down. If WoL works now but not after a shutdown, you need to replace/update the driver. If not, there might be a missing BIOS option (look for *PME*). All vendor-provided drivers I've seen do support WoL.

Comment: Absolutely a possibility to get WOL disabled if the NIC is not reset on shutdown.